# Are the columns in $AB$ linear combinations of the columns in $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reviewing matrix multiplication, and in my text book, they assumed that the columns in a matrix $AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of a matrix $A$. I can't really see why this is the case.

Does anyone have a quick "proof" of this statement?

Thanks.

Comment: There is really no proof to be had. Just write the two matrices as columns and carry out multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$ be a vector of appropriate dimension. Let $\mathbf{a_1}, \mathbf{a_2}, \dots \mathbf{a_n}$ be the columns of $A$. Then,

$$
Ax = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{a_i}
$$

which is clearly a linear combination of columns of $A$.

If $\mathbf{b_1}, \mathbf{b_2}, \dots \mathbf{b_m}$ are the columns of $B$, then the $i$-th column of $AB$ is $A\mathbf{b_i}$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$ (proved above). This is true for any $i$.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm still not able to figure this out. When you state that Ax is a linear combination of columns of A, aren't we in fact multiplying each row, and not column, of A, with the single column vector x?

Comment: @Tanamas, you have it backwards, each row of x multiplied by each column of A. Refer [here](https://mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)

Comment: @OwenMurphy I don't see how Tanamas has it backwards? The matrix product is defined by taking the dot product of the rows of A by the columns of B, so how does Priyatham's multiplication work here? They are multiplying the columns of the first matrix by the rows of the second, which isn't how the product is defined. I'm confused here